# Multivariable limit of $\left(x^2+y^2 \right) \frac{1}{\sin xy}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find multivariable limit of: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\left(x^2+y^2 \right) \frac{1}{\sin xy}$$
How to find it my attempt was to substitute $(x_n,y_n)=(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ and $(x^{\prime}_n ,y^{\prime}_n )=(\frac{1}{n}, - \frac{1}{n})$, but i do not think this substitution helps, it does not simplify anything later on. How to find this limit properly?

Comment: If you investigate your own examples, you will find that they give you different limits. Can you verify it? Then what can you conclude from it?

Comment: I do not think so, from my examples it is clear that if we use those two paths the result is in both cases zero.

Comment: You should get $2$ and $-2$, respectively. One way to see this is to write $$ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{\sin xy} = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy} \frac{xy}{\sin xy} $$ and consider only the first fraction term, since we know that $\sin r / r \to 1$ as $r \to 0$.

Comment: We often say informally that $0/0$ form is indeterminate, which means that we have no unversal way of predicting how the ratio of two vanishing quantities will behave. You cannot say that something does not converge simply because the denomiantor goes to 0. And this is the case in your limit.

Comment: understand, thank you very much

Comment: Glad you found an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What happens when $y=x$ and when $y=2x$?

Comment: $\frac{3x^2}{\sin 2x^2} $ and $\frac{2x^2}{\sin x^2} $ i guess limit does not exist, but how to show that?

Comment: @mkropkowski The limit exists if and only if the function approaches it regardless of how $x$ and $y$ approach $0$. But recalling that $x/\sin x \to 1 $ ... ( by the way, you meant $5$ in place of $3$; $2$ has been squared)

Answer (score 0):

One has:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\left(x^2+y^2 \right) \frac{1}{\sin xy}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{ xy}$$
If we put $y=mx$,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{ xy}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2+m^2 x^2}{ m x^2}=\frac{1+m^2}{m}$$
Then the limit doesn't exists.